# An Equivalence Statement of Two Expected Values

Tags: expected-value, equivalence

Suppose that we have three random variables, $V_1,\;V_2,\;V_3$.

I derived an equivalence statement through a pretty long derivation:
$$\mathbb{E}[V_1|V_2=v_2,\;c>V_3]=\mathbb{E}\left[\;\mathbb{E}\{V_1|V_2=v_2,V_3\}\;|\;V_2=v_2,\;c>V_3\right]$$

I guess, it is a kind of LIE (law of iterated expectation).

Does the statement seem natural?

Comment: Yes, it is. Note that since $V_2$ is fixed, it is sort of irrelevant for the reasoning.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for the cross validation :)